# RebindableSyntax does not work as expected

Tags: haskell

When I define `>>` function (with `RebindableSyntax` extension) and use it directly (`mempty >> 1 >> 2 >> 3`) everything works as expected, but when I use do block I get following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’
            with actual type ‘Aggregator Integer’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: 1
In the expression:
  do mempty
     1
     2
     3
In an equation for ‘notWorking’:
    notWorking
      = do mempty
           1
           2
           3
```

Whole code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE  RebindableSyntax #-}

module RebindableSyntaxStuff where

import Prelude hiding ((>>), (>>=), return)

newtype Aggregator a = Aggregator [a]
    deriving(Show)

instance Semigroup (Aggregator a) where
    (Aggregator xs) <> (Aggregator ys) = Aggregator (xs++ys)

instance Monoid (Aggregator a) where
    mempty = Aggregator []

pack :: a -> Aggregator a
pack x = Aggregator [x]

working :: Aggregator Integer
working = mempty >> 1 >> 2 >> 3 --Returns Aggregator [1,2,3]

notWorking :: Aggregator Integer
notWorking = do
    mempty
    1
    2
    3

(>>) :: Aggregator Integer -> Integer -> Aggregator Integer
(>>) a b = (<>) a (pack b)
```

As I understand `do` will add `>>` on every new line, so it should work.
Where did I make a mistake?

## Solution

> The way Haskell desugars the do notation is right associative

I changed `(>>)` function to be `infixr` and also order of arguments. Code below:

```hs
working :: Aggregator Integer
working = 1 >> 2 >> 3 >> mempty 

notWorking :: Aggregator Integer
notWorking = do -- Now works
    1
    2
    3
    mempty

infixr 0 >>
(>>) :: Integer -> Aggregator Integer -> Aggregator Integer
(>>) a = (<>) (pack a)
```

Comment: It uses `(>>)`, but not the `(>>)` function you defined here, but the one from the `Monad` typeclass.

Comment: Even with this `import Prelude hiding ((>>), (>>=), return)
` line?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, did not see the `RebindableSyntax`, the problem is that do notation is right associative, so `do { mempty; 1; 2; 3 }` is interpreted as `mempty >> (1 >> (2 >> 3))`, and hence the problem. Because the left operand in `2 >> 3` is an `Integer` as well.

Comment: I think it's probably associating to the right, so what it actually turns the `do` block into is `mempty >> (1 >> (2 >> 3))`

Comment: Honestly, what you're doing seems like a pretty horrible idea. Use `RebindableSyntax` to _generalise_ existing signatures, not to make syntactic constructs do something completely different.

Comment: I'm trying to implement simple edsl

Comment: Well, it's not much of an _embedded_ DSL if it interferes with the parent language, as your custom `>>` would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define your operator like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
(>>) :: Integer -> Aggregator Integer -> Aggregator Integer
(>>) a b = (<>) (pack a) b
```

And then you can do this:

```
finallyWorks :: Aggregator Integer
finallyWorks = do
    1
    2
    3
    mempty
```

The reason is that Haskell's `do` syntax is defined to use the `>>` operator in a right-associative fashion. `do { mempty; 1; 2; 3; }` ends up being read as `mempty >> (1 >> (2 >> 3))` The `>>` operator itself is left-associative, so your manual example `mempty >> 1 >> 2 >> 3` is read as `((mempty >> 1) >> 2) >> 3`; not the same thing.

I believe this is because the rules for desugaring `do` blacks that bind variables (using the `>>=` operator rather than `>>`) *have* to associate to the right. This:

```
do r1 <- action1
   r2 <- action2 r1
   f r2
```

Desugars to this:

```
action1 >>= (\r1 -> action2 r1 >>= (\r2 -> f r2))
```

Fundamentally the later actions in the do block need to be "nested inside" the lambdas binding the results of the earlier actions, in order for those results to be in scope. This is what leads to the right-associative nature of lines in a `do` block.

The actual `>>` operator from `Monad` is in principle associative, so `a >> (b >> c)` has the same end result as `(a >> b) >> c`. So `do` blocks like yours that don't bind any variables could in theory desugar to left-associative applications of `>>`. But since `>>` is associative, there was no reason *not* to desugar `do` lines without variables in a similar manner to those that do bind variables.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or `a >> (Aggregator b) = Aggregator (a : b)`. It looks like it should even be `(>>) = coerce (:)`, but it doesn't work without a type annotation on the `:`, which made it not look so nice anymore.

Answer (score 4):

> As I understand do will add `>>` on every new line, so it should work.

The way [Haskell desugars the `do` notation](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) is right associative. Indeed, if you write:

```
do {
    mempty;
    1;
    2;
    3
}
```

then this is desugared to:

```
mempty >> do {
    1;
    2;
    3
}
```

and thus further to:

```
mempty >> (1 >> do {
    2;
    3
})
```

if we keep desugaring, we eventually obtain `mempty >> (1 >> (2 >> 3))`. This matters because here we have expressions like `1 >> …`, and `2 >> …` where the left operand is an `Num a => a`, and not a `Aggregator Integer`.

If we for example define a function like:

```
(>>) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(>>) = (+)
```

then we can write a `do` block:

```
six :: Integer
six = do
    1
    2
    3
```

it will return:

```
*RebindableSyntaxStuff> six
6
```

Comment: Ok, I adapted my code to this. Solution in question post. Thanks